# Mysql Why zero result is showing?

Tags: mysql, database

[Image of Database contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYHNz.png)

I am trying to fetch data from the database by using the following query but the result is not getting accordingly.

```
select * 
from `consolidation_requests` 
where `user_id` = 23  
and `compiling_status` = 'consolidation' 
and shipment_status !='cencel by user'
```

Comment: Please always provide data as text not image

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will return false for comparisons against NULL. Try

```
select * 
from `consolidation_requests` 
where `user_id` = 23  
and `compiling_status` = 'consolidation' 
and (shipment_status !='cencel by user' OR shipment_status IS NULL)
```